# Wifi broadcom, ubuntu 14.04 , Dell Vostro - still diconnecting -need help

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

Sorry I know that this problem was on this forum ,  but I tried to do everything, resolve the problem and I ... no result.

What I try:
change kernel to 3.18, and 3.19
change driver, disable N standard,

and problem still exist on my notebook.

Need some help please.
Sorry for my english.

#### wireless info START

Report from: 18 Jun 2015 00:04 CEST +0200

Booted last: 17 Jun 2015 22:57 CEST +0200

Script from: 21 May 2015 09:10 UTC +0000

release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

kernel

Linux 3.13.0-55-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:32:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

desktop

Ubuntu

lspci

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0558]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6495 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCMCIA card info

rfkill

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lsmod

wl                   4207846  0 
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
dell_wmi               12761  0 
cfg80211              484040  1 wl
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            18168  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi

interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:164.127.21.246  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:20353414 (20.3 MB)  TX bytes:2238144 (2.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          inet6 addr: fe80::e206:e6ff:fed2:eced/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:23119
          TX packets:15259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12314071 (12.3 MB)  TX bytes:2998369 (2.9 MB)
          Interrupt:19

wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

iwconfig

wwan0     no wireless extensions.

ppp0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0

resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.1.1

network managers

Installed:

```
NetworkManager
```

Running:

root       828     1  0 Jun17 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

NetworkManager info

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: ttyUSB1  [Play Online Default] ---------------------------------------
  Type:              Mobile Broadband (GSM)
  Driver:            option1, huawei_cdc_ncm
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes

  Capabilities:

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         164.127.21.246
  Prefix:          32 (255.255.255.255)
  Gateway:         10.64.64.64

  DNS:             89.108.202.20
  DNS:             89.108.195.20
- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:

  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         off
- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
  WEP Encryption:  yes
  WPA Encryption:  yes
  WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
  UPC0831643:      Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
  kowal:           Infra, , Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WPA
  UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WPA2 Enterprise
  MF28d-55D192:    Infra, , Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 69 WPA WPA2

NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

NetworkManager profiles

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/kowal]] (600 root)
[connection] id=kowal | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=kowal | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

iw reg get

Region: Europe/Warsaw (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

iwlist channels

wwan0     no frequency information.

ppp0      no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     26 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz

iwlist scan

wwan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

ppp0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

```
  2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
```

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"kowal"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC0831643"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC Wi-Free"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 04 - Address: 
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MF28d-55D192"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

module infos

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-55-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     FF25FE784DC6BDFF69DAFCB
depends:        cfg80211,lib80211
vermagic:       3.13.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-55-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     22618C9A8AD682CBE73FFF2
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-55-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        87:25:09:9B:5C:DE:49:A8:22:14:CC:2B:CD:03:31:B1:EB:B1:44:AD
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

module parameters

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

/etc/modules

lp
rtc

modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/wireless-bcm43142-dkms.conf]
blacklist b44
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b43
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

rc.local

echo 1464 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
exit 0

pm-utils

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

udev rules

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]

## PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

## PCI device 0x14e4:0x4365 (wl)

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

dmesg

[   16.751381] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   16.933893] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4365 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.141 (r415941)
[   17.048671] usb 1-1.4: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   17.049298] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[ 4078.480217] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)

#### wireless info END

mariusz@mariusz-dell:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)